# What should I do to improve the quality of the screen capture?

Tags: video, youtube, video-recording, packet-capture

I'm creating videos to post to YouTube.

My videos are about some jobs I do on the computer.

I watched some of my videos posted and that the quality of the video capture was not very good and clear.

**What should I do to improve the quality of the screen capture?**

To use better software?

I'm using [Windows Media Encoder](https://www.microsoft.com/pt-pt/download/details.aspx?id=98)

Comment: Have you tried saving it in another format like tiff or jpeg.  I think the default is png.

Comment: I would suggest just using a new software. I use Camtasia, and it’s great.

Comment: What You mean by Quality? General video quality like resolution,  compression artifacts and blurry. Or special functions like mouse highlight, click and double-click indication, automatic hotkey subtitles , etc ?

Answer (score 1):

Does it look bad after you upload it to YouTube or does it look bad on your computer already? Does the quality get noticeably worse after you upload it to YouTube?

You should probably switch to a software that supports H.264 encoding, which is the recommended format for YouTube. Try capturing and uploading very short videos first, increase the bitrate until you're satisfied with the quality. You may even try setting it to lossless when capturing, so that when YouTube re-encodes your video, the quality is lost only once (instead of twice: when you're capturing and then when you're uploading).

Plenty of software support H.264, including some free software, for example, [OBS](https://obsproject.com/).

Answer (score 1):

To just capture desktop video on Windows I use [ShareX](https://getsharex.com). It's free and opensource.